# Disable mouse pointer text selector when hovering above text

Tags: javascript, css, html

Every time you hover over text the mouse turns in to this text selector that pops up instead of the mouse icon, How do i disable this in CSS/JS/HTML when hovering over specific paragraphs containing the same class? Could this be done in CSS?
for example i dont want to have a hover option over this:

```
<p class="class">Dont hover over me</p>
```

Comment: Just a guess: `p:hover { cursor: default }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **[cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)** property:

```
p.class {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
.class:hover{
   cursor:default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the [CSS `cursor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor):

```
p.class {
     cursor: default;
}
```

to disable the `text` style.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cursor: default;
```

In your CSS.  Look up the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp